# printing values in a different sequence using a multi-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

im working on a question where i need to print a N*N multi-dimensional array in the following format: if N = 3, then:

```
4 2 1
7 5 3
9 8 6
```

im stuck in writing the for loop for this. im not able to get the logic or how do start the printing of the values.
my code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;


public class Hotel {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N=1, x=1, y=0, f=1;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the size of square: ");
    x = in.nextInt();
    if (x>=1 && x<=100) {
        N = x;
    }
    y=N*N;
    int[][] arr = new int[N][N];

            arr[0][N-1] = f;
            arr[N-1][0] = y;
            for(int i=0; i<N;i++) {
                  for (int j=0;j<N;j++) {
                       -------------------------------

                        }
                  }


    for(int i=0; i<N;i++) {
          for (int j=0;j<N;j++) {
              System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " "); // Printing a 2d array
              }   
          System.out.println(" ");
      }

in.close();
    }

}
```

My output according to my code:

```
0 0 1
0 0 0
9 0 0
```

the inner for loops, im not able to get the logic. if u can help me in giving a logic, i will try to work it out. kindly help

Answer (score 2):

When solving problems like this, you should think about the steps you are taking in a very systematic way. Basically, you should recite every step you expect your algorithm to take to yourself, without doing any 'reasoning'.

What you should *not* do, is steps like:

"Ok, I put 2 in the upper middle spot, so now i need to go down diagonnaly to the right."

You need to find the pattern to what you want to do. In this case you want to make diagonal lines of numbers, so you need to detect when to start a new line.
When should you start a new line? Well, once the current one is finished, of course. When is a line finished? When there is no legal spot at (x + 1, y + 1), where your current spot is (x, y).

So your algorithm should detect this situation, and then find the starting position for your next line. Where does your next line start?  If you just store the coordinates of the starting point of the *previous* line, then it should be 1 less than those.

You now know where to start and end your lines, so now all you need is to initialise and terminate your algorithm.

The upper right position will always hold a 1, so you can put that in right away. You have an extra variable storing x-cooridnates, so you need to set that to the value of your first 'line', which is N-1. Now, the algorithm as described above will see that the line cannot continue, and start the next line.

When does your algorithm terminate? There are several ways to do this, but the easiest is to simply look at the number you would enter next. Your square is N*N, so that should be the largest number entered. If you detect that the next number you *would* enter would be N*N + 1, then you're done. Alternatively, you could check your 'starting x', if that's less than 0, you're not going to be able to write any more values.

Comment: I'll leave it to you to detect when you need to go down instead of left when starting the next line.